# NET-SSH2 for perl 5.20.2 on windows 2008 r2

Tags: perl, windows-server-2008-r2, net-ssh, perlnetssh

I am trying to install `NET-SSH2` for `perl 5.20.2` on `windows 2008r2` but no success.

> C:\Perl>ppm install NET-SSH2
>   Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...failed 500 Can't connect to ppm4.activestate.com:80
>   ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides NET-SSH2

please help

Comment: This question seems off-topic since is not strictly related to programming, perhaps it is better for [http://superuser.com/questions](http://superuser.com/questions)

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=949926

Comment: i have net-ssh2 for perl module 5.14 but can anyone tell me how can i get net-ssh2 for perl 5.20.2. my scripts are not working on new version of perl because of NET-SSH2 not there in lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net::SSH2 is not in offical PPM repositories. Install it using below:

```
ppm install http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/Net-SSH2.ppd
```

Tested on Windows 7 and Perl 5.18.4

[image]